# Which Visual C/C++ run-time library to pick?

Tags: c++, linker, sdl, msvcrt

I've stumbled upon the issues with having the wrong MSVC run-time when linking or running apps written in C or C++. Because of that, I try to be exact on using the correct versions.

I see that the SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) library is pre-compiled with MSVCRT, which AFAIK is compiled with MSVC 4.2 to 6.0. Still, that pre-compiled library works fine with my apps compiled with the much later Visual Studio 2015 v14.

1. How come there are no issue with linking old MSVCRT with MSVCR140, e.g. SDL?
2. Is there a way to make a library be compatible with any greater Visual Studio compiler?
3. How is this solved with using other compilers, e.g. GCC or even on Linux or Mac?

Comment: Make it a static library - that way you won't have problems with any package

Comment: Still, how come the pre-compiled SDL library not cause any issues?

Comment: Cross-platform libraries usually start out in Unix, making it compatible with the many Unix flavors is the first concern.  And would favor an open source compiler like GCC.  Getting that ported to Windows usually involves MinGW.  Which did not write its own runtime library, it uses msvcrt.dll.  Having more than one copy of the CRT loaded in a program is pretty risky, the library interface has to be carefully designed.  But surely SDL got that right.  Not otherwise different from using the winapi, it also uses msvcrt.dll.  And was carefully designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because the, let's call them vintage, runtimes are used so widely they're always there. But more recent runtimes, used by a newer Visual C++, might not be automatically present. Also, Visual C++ standardised on a single runtime library for some time, ensuring backwards compatibility with existing applications. Somewhere around Visual Studio 2012 this was dropped in favor of version specific runtimes.
2. You need to package your application into an installer that also installs the necessary runtime (or runtimes if you require more than one).
3. Linux applications are packaged (RPM, YUM etc.) with dependencies on runtime components. Basicaly the same as a Windows installer. Dependencies are either part of the package or satified by the distro. Linux shared libraries are versioned, multiple versions can be installed side-by-side and an applications can link against specific versions if required.